# VBA to sum value for specific cells

Tags: excel, vba, function, sum

[worksheet column fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3efg.png)

I am looking to see whether its possible to write a VBA which will do a basic sum function based on account name. The screenshot i've attached is of the master worksheet from my workbook. So, for the account named ALBAR, I would be looking to get a sum figure for their revenue by having a VBA which activates a sum function for all of their daily trading activity in the individual worksheets in the workbook.

My question is, it possible to have this sum function in a VBA whereby it will search for the name ALBAR across the different worksheets in the excel file and return a sum figure for the master worksheet?

Edit: I have now added a second picture detailing to columns for the daily worksheets where the master worksheet should derive its data from.

[Daily activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDfDK.png)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done via a simple formula:

`=SUMIFS(AccountRange;RevenueRange;"=ALBAR")`

Comment: hi @vthomas I've tried to use the sumifs as you described but it gave me an error. I've now attached a second screenshot showing the column labels for each daily worksheet. If I told you that the column I need the data from (in addition to account name of course) is Value of trade $, how would you edit the sumif function? Thanks, its appreciated

Comment: You want the criteria to apply on the column A and the formula to add up the content of column I.
So you should use the formula with those columns:
`=SUMIFS($A:$A;$I:$I;"=ALBAR")`

Comment: I have tried that function and it is still producing an error. Thank you for the advice